# SSRS cascade filters not working properly

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have multiple cascade filters in my report. First being Department filter which has options (All,Finance, HR, Ops), Director filter which is dependent on the Department filter section by default has (All, Rob, Meg, Tim). Now when Finance is selected the correct Director is being selected i.e 'Rob'. But when I select All for Department filter, my Director filter still stuck at 'Rob' and didn't automatically select All.

P.S: I have set Available and Default values of Director to the Director dataset
which is as below:

```
Select distinct ISNULL(Director,'') 
Director from Table
```

Comment: surely you need a where cause to filter by the selected department, e.g. `SELECT ISNULL(Director, '') FROM Table WHERE Department = @Department`  `@Department` being your SSRS department parameter name.

Comment: Right but still the same issue.

Comment: Defaults only work when the report is first loaded. They don't get refreshed when the selection changes unless the current selection is not in the updated available selection.